# Are there any melodicas out there that use steel reeds?

Tags: instruments, reeds, melodica

Or another ferromagnetic material.

Most Harmonicas use Brass reeds, I think Seydel is the only exception, who make the "session steel", a stainless steel reeded harmonica.  Seydel don't make melodicas apart from one toy one though.

Does anyone know if *anyone* makes steel (or other ferromagnetic alloy) reeded melodicas?

Comment: Are you sure that the alloy is ferromagnetic? Only some stainless steel alloys are so, and being magnetic would seem to be a liability with regard to keeping its pitch as becoming magnetized would cause interaction with other ferromagnetic parts.

Comment: @user44740 Thanks for your comment.  Yes I am sure, they are definitely ferromagnetic

Answer (score 1):

The **Borel Clavietta** used stainless steel reeds, as did the **Guerrini Pianetta**; however, I cannot find information on their ferromagnetic properties.

A discussion on Melodicaworld, titled [La Clavietta Stainless Steel Reed](https://melodicaworld.com/forums/topic/la-clavietta-stainless-steel-reed/) discusses the Clavietta and Pianetta, their reeds, and how to effect a repair.

> Today the Middle B note of my beautiful Clavietta stopped working. I opened it up and a tiny metal reed fell out.... [David Elizabeth, January 19, 2017 at 7:18 pm]

> Other Italian melodicas (ca. 1970) ... have similar individual reed plates and reeds. [Alan Brinton, January 20, 2017 at 2:53 am]

> At least some of the small Italians do not have smaller reeds than the Clavietta.... In terms of size and material, they don’t appear to be different. [Alan Brinton, January 20, 2017 at 6:56 pm]

> I have a Pianetta ... with a failed reed.... A reed from a Clavietta is the best bet.... [Alan Brinton, January 21, 2017 at 12:22 am]

> The reed itself should be stainless, but the reed plate is aluminum, that has been anodized. [Melodica-Me, January 30, 2017 at 6:39 am]

Here is a listing for a [Borel Clavietta for sale](https://reverb.com/item/17312472-melodica-borel-clavietta-1950-pearl-white). It specifically mentions the "Swedish stainless steel" reed type.

> Reed type: Single reed plates, Stainless Swedish Steel

That listing also makes reference to the "Accordina", which is a [button-controlled version](https://www.patmissin.com/history/accordina.html) of the same instrument.

Accordinas are still being made and use stainless steel reeds. For example, from the site https://www.accordina.com/:

> **Special Stainless Steel Reeds**: Specially studied and made to measure in Italy, unalterable stainless steel reeds are mounted directly on the reed block....